# WPF: Which properties are applied to the ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, controltemplate

I'd like to understand which properties of an xaml Control are applied to the ControlTemplate of that Control. 
F.e. If I create a Control based on the Window Class like this:
*(This is very simplified — It doesn't make sense in the current state I know...)*

```
public class BaseWindow : Window {
   public BaseWindow() { }
}
```

And the Template:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Shell"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Arctic">



    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BaseWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BaseWindow}">



                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>



                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

Now, when I specify a BaseWindow Control in my app the Margin Property is applied to the BaseWindow without specifying a TemplateBinding. The Background isn't, I have to declare the TemplateBinding in the Template in order to achieve that. 
Can you explain to me why some properties are applied to the ControlTemplate by default and others are not?
My guess is, that the Window.xaml (Default Window Template of WPF) binds to some properties like the Margin but ignores some like Background. If that is true, then I do not understand why I can set the Background in a Window Control and it is applied to it. Seems like the Window binds to some properties and stops doing that when you derive from it…
This is probably completely wrong — I just wanted to explain my thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window` class inherit `FrameworkElement` and all its properties including `FrameworkElement.Margin`. Same goes for `Control.Background`. Your question is why you have to do something to have `Control.Background` working.

Answer is simple:

- `Margin` is used in layouting, its functionality is implemented/provided by `FrameworkElement` and it happens always, invisible for you and disregarding of `ControlTemplate` (because **all** framework elements participate in layouting and use margin).
- `Background`, in turn, is provided to be use by visuals. It's up to you how to use it, because **only you** know how control will looks like. `Control` doesn't know what to do with that property.

So, you have to use `TemplateBinding` to bind `Background` to some color in your `ControlTemplate`, but `Margin` works without need to do anything in control template.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I can basically check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(v=vs.110).aspx and all these properties, such as Cursor or min-height are applied automatically?

Comment: You have to think about each property differently. `Cursor` will be applied *automagically*, yes, but your framework element have to provide something what can be mouseovered. If there is nothing - it will not work. `Margin` and `MinHeight` will work always because *all* `FrameworkElement` participate in layouting, e.g. setting `MinHeight` will reserve that height in measure and arrange pass. You can read [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx).